# Why locate command doesn't recognize `|` meta character as basic regex?

Tags: regular-expression, locate

When i use extended regex on `locate` command work well:

```
└─$ locate --regex "(\.rar|\.zip)"                                                    
/home/kali/Downloads/linux.zip
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/legal/jdk.zipfs
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/legal/jdk.zipfs/ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
/usr/share/exploitdb/exploits/windows/remote/17419.zip
/usr/share/icons/Flat-Remix-Blue-Dark/mimetypes/scalable/application-vnd.rar.svg
/usr/share/mime/application/vnd.rar.xml
/usr/share/powershell-empire/empire/server/csharp/Covenant/Data/EmbeddedResources/Lib.zip
/usr/share/powershell-empire/empire/server/data/misc/python_modules/keyboard.zip
/usr/share/powershell-empire/empire/server/data/misc/python_modules/mss.zip
/usr/share/set/src/teensy/x10/libraries.zip
```

But when i use basic regex, `locate` not recognize `|` metacharcater:

```
└─$ locate --regexp "(\.rar\|\.zip)"                                                     

└─$
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `|` isn't part of POSIX BREs, and neither is `\|`, so that might well be the reason. If you have an ERE that works and you can use it, why not just use it?

Comment: I just wondered. Thank you for your response. @ilkkachu